# How to change the data type to currency in Access query

Tags: ms-access

I made a query where I had to add `10%` to the net income field but I can't change it to the currency data type. Is there a way to do it?

This is a picture of the error I get when I try to change the data type to currency:

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Format` function to display it correctly:

```
Format([Net Income] * 1.1,"Currency")
```

Normally query used as data source for forms and reports, not directly. So, it would be better to format the number in the form/report, `Format` function returns string and you may have problems in further data conversions, for instance, if this query will be used in other queries.

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me mate!

Answer (score 0):

right click on the top of your tbl. then do design view. select the net income field. change data type to curreny

Answer (score 0):

right click on your query table next to the function, then click properties, then on the property sheet under General click format then select currency.